# Why there are two speeds written on the CPU?

Tags: intel-core-i7, cpu-speed

When looking on the details of some of Intel’s CPU, it looks for example like this:

> Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.59 GHz

What is the meaning of each speed rate?

Comment: Where are you looking? https://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz?q=i7-6500U lists "Processor Base Frequency 2.50 GHz" and "Max Turbo Frequency 3.10 GHz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is usually the base/standard frequency and the second one is usually the turbo/max frequency. [Looking up the specs for the Intel® Core™ i7-6500U](https://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz?q=Core%E2%84%A2%20i7-6500U) on Intel’s website shows the following details; specs seem different than yours for reference:

- **Processor Base Frequency**: 2.50 GHz
- **Max Turbo Frequency**: 3.10 GHz

And clicking on the “?” help links next each term shows the following:

- **Processor Base Frequency**: Processor Base Frequency describes the rate at which the processor's transistors open and close. The processor base frequency is the operating point where TDP is defined. Frequency is measured in gigahertz (GHz), or billion cycles per second.
- **Max Turbo Frequency**: Max turbo frequency is the maximum single core frequency at which the processor is capable of operating using Intel® Turbo Boost Technology. Frequency is measured in gigahertz (GHz), or billion cycles per second.

Comment: It seems right, thanks a lot!
I got this from my System Properties, I don't know why it is different from the information at Intel's site.

Answer (score -1):

These stats appear to be the processor base frequency and the configurable TDP-up frequency,  respectfully.  Intel provides further information on their site.